# jpackage (java15) can't create a Windows x86 Installer

Tags: java, wix, jpackage

I tried a lot of different approaches but always failed.

I successfully generated an x64 installer for my java jar (spring boot runnable), but I'm unable to create the x86 version of the installer.

After moving to a x86 virtual machine, I downloaded the zulu jdk 15 whom is able to run my software (manually), so I tried to run the jpackage tool, but it creates an installer for an x64 system.

As I could not find any additional parameter, i tried to verbose log the jpackage tool and found that 'candle' is called with the wrong arch (I replaced paths and variables to shorten path!

```
 [candle.exe, -nologo, TMPDIR\config\main.wxs,
 -ext, WixUtilExtension, -arch, x64, 
 -out, TMPDIR\wixobj\main.wixobj,
 -dJpAppDescription=DESCRIPTION, -dJpProductCode=UUID, -dJpAppName=APPNAME, 
 -dJpIsSystemWide=yes, -dJpAllowDowngrades=yes, -dJpIcon=TMPDIR\images\win-msi.image\APPNAME\APPNAME.exe, 
 -dJpAppVersion=1.0.0, -dJpInstallDirChooser=yes, -dJpAllowUpgrades=yes, -dJpProductUpgradeCode=UUID2,
 -dJpAppVendor=VENDOR, -dJpConfigDir=TMPDIR\config]
```

if I manually launch the command with -arch x86 it fails telling that Intelx64 files are missing (there is a preparation of wxs file before candle i suppose).

Does anyone fixed this issue?

Comment: If you're intending to create a 32-bit installer, I'm guessing you're going to have to do that on a 32 machine with an appropriate JDK. Hope you can find one with jpackage

Comment: yes, i created a 32bit jvm and using a 32bit openjdk version with jpackage. That's the starting point of the question

Comment: Confusion: you *created* a 32 bit vm, not a jvm ;) I'm saying you might need 32-bit metal, not virtualization. Even if you *could* get it to work, it wouldn't be as trustworthy

Comment: No confusion: I created a 32bit VM of windows 10, then I downloaded a version of the jdk 15 that is x86 https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-15-mts&os=windows&architecture=x86-32-bit#zulu and went through jpackage. The issue here is with jpackage that creates a x64 installer (see the command -arch !)

Comment: If your x86 jpackage cannot create a 32 bit installer, then you'll need to fall back on 3rd party tools

Comment: There's code that should handle this in jpackage: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.jpackage/windows/classes/jdk/jpackage/internal/WixFragmentBuilder.java#L104 If you launch `jshell` from the x86 JDK, and enter `System.getProperty("os.arch")` what does it print?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to launch it but i'm quite sure it will give x86. On this, I see from the commits that the file has been added in 2021, so maybe it is not part of jdk15, so i'll have to find out since when it has been added!

Comment: You're right, it was fixed in JDK 17: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8258755 If you're an Azul customer, you might be able to ask them to backport the fix to JDK 15.

Comment: Ok, it should not be a problem as I can use JDK 17 to build the package but attach my custom created runtime with java15! Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: I tried with Zulu jdk17 32bit but was not successful, Zulu says 17.0.7 and looking at the commits it seems a newer version... I'll try to find another jdk or search for a jdk 19! I'll try temurin jdk 18 or 19. Let's see!

Comment: Nothing to do, now jdks 17,18 and 19 correctly call "candle" with arch -x86 but the installer hangs (a small window opens for some milliseconds then hides and I see the process in activity manager). I'll give up and go for Innosetup if noone have clues... 
Too bad, the 32bit installer works on my Windows11 64bit machine (saying it is 32bit), so I dont' know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different software for preparing the installer following the guide of the SweetHome3D ( https://sweethome3d.com/ ) creator:

http://www.eteks.com/tips/tipCreationExe.html

It did not work using candle and wxs so there is no real solution, just the alternative for 32bit.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't have the correct/latest versions of .NET and supporting software

Comment: Don't think so, the problem was on jpackage not sending correct arch, then there was something on the created installer (hangs), so Innosetup helped.
The funny thing is that the 32bit exe works on x64 machine but not on 32bit. Funny :D